# Can you access scores for each boosting round in LightGBM.train()?

Tags: python, lightgbm

**Basic Info**

`lgbm.train(`) with `early_stopping` calculates the objective function & `feval` scores after each boost round, and we can make it print those every `verbose_eval` rounds, like so:

```
bst=lgbm.train(**params)
[10]    valid_0's binary_logloss: 0.215654  valid_0's BinaryError: 0.00775126
[20]    valid_0's binary_logloss: 0.303113  valid_0's BinaryError: 0.00790619
[30]    valid_0's binary_logloss: 0.358056  valid_0's BinaryError: 0.0838744
[40]    valid_0's binary_logloss: 0.386763  valid_0's BinaryError: 0.138462
[50]    valid_0's binary_logloss: 0.411467  valid_0's BinaryError: 0.176986
```

**Question:**

Is there any way to access a list of these scores for each boosting round?

The closest thing I can find in the documentation
& `bst.__dict__` is `bst.best_score`

```
defaultdict(collections.OrderedDict,
             {'valid_0': OrderedDict([('binary_logloss', 0.4233895131745753),
                           ('BinaryError', 0.194285077972568)])})
```

Comment: PS. In theory I could take the bst object and loop over `bst.predict(X_validation, num_iteration=n)` and manually score output at each boost round, but that is a waste of compute resources....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `evals_result` parameter as follows;

```
evals_result = {}

bst=lgbm.train(evals_result=evals_result, valid_sets = [valid_set, train_set],
               valid_names = [‘valid’, ‘train’], **params)

evals_result
>>> {‘train’: {‘logloss’: [‘0.36483’, ‘0.32617’, …]}, ‘valid’: {‘logloss’: [‘0.479168’, ‘0.317850’, …]}}
```

You will have a dictionary for both train and valid set scores for each boosting round.

Comment: Awesome.  I'd totally missed that; the dict isn't part of the output object so wasn't in the booster docs....

Comment: Yes it's little tricky but efficient, I'm happy to solve your problem :)